# Permanently disable color in default terminal

Tags: colors

I can't figure out how to disable the colors in the terminal(just the default, gnu it's called?). Been looking for an hour and ran some code that I saw else where. Also tried **emacs ~/.bashrc** and added a line that was supposed to disable the color, it worked once then I closed the terminal, **ls** again, and the colors were back. Any help is great!

Comment: if you want it for just 1 command put a \ in front of the command ;-) (`\ls -l` will drop the colors too for that 1 time).

Comment: I need it permanently! haha but i'll remember that in case I am in ssh and tired of the color when I ls

Comment: I tried and couldn't quite get this to work, but shouldn't there be a way to do this by going into the preferences of the terminal emulator and setting all the colours to be black, white or grey?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` file, you'll find lines

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
```

Put a `#` comment sign in front of `force_color_prompt=yes` line and restart terminal. After the change, the line should be

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

**Edit:** This will turn of the color from terminal. But if some programs has color support built-in in them and if you want to turn them off too, follow @Zanna's answer. Basically you need to comment out the lines like `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` etc.

Comment: There was already a **#** in front of **force_color_prompt=yes** when I opened it up, and I haven't touched that before. Weird, anything else I could try?

Comment: That will set the color off. but some programs have color support such as `ls` and for stopping those colors, you need to comment out those lines. Zanna's answer show you how to do that

Comment: Yeah I also followed Zanna's answer and the color is still there.. Not sure what else to try

Comment: @KyleDrummond exit terminal and start it again

Comment: Haha, the simple stuff is what always gets me. Good now! Thanks!

Comment: @KyleDrummond I am confused why you accepted Anwar's answer. Although Anwar's answer is correct, you never uncommented `force_color_prompt` in the first place, so this solution, while correct, does not solve your problem. The real solution that works is provided by Zanna.

Comment: @edwinksl May be it because her answer didn't work first place without my exit terminal and start it again' comment!

Answer (score 11):

If you have set a coloured prompt see @Anwar's answer

The colours from the output of commands such as `ls` are made by aliases.

To disable this, find and comment out (by inserting # at the start of the line) these lines in your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

when done, `source ~/.bashrc` to get the immediate effect or just close the terminal and open a new one

Comment: That didn't work either. All of those are commented out and I ran **source ~/.bashrc** after I saved it.

Comment: @KyleDrummond that's weird but I see you got it working by opening a new terminal. btw, Anwar's answer just tells you how to stop the prompt (`user@mycomputer:~$`) from being colored, this one tells you how to stop colors in output from commands like `ls` which I think is what you wanted? Could you clarify as you accepted the other answer?

Comment: I've commented out the "force_color_prompt=yes" as @Anwar said and I've disabled all the lines you specified and yes the output of ls and grep doesn't show colors but the prompt is still colored.

Answer (score 1):

## A simple, elegant solution.

No code needed for "GNOME terminal": just follow these steps:

1. Run `gnome-terminal`.
2. Go to Terminal > Preferences.
3. Go to Profiles.
4. Select the profile you use, then click Clone.
5. Go to Colours.
6. Replace every color of the bottom row with `#EEEEEC` or the rightmost color you have set.
7. Replace every color of the top row with `#300A24` (default GTK theme background color) or the one your theme has. If you have disabled the system theme, set them to the "Background colour" instead.

Now you are almost done, but I recommend you to do these steps:

1. Go to General
2. Change the profile name to something like `<PROFILE> (monochrome)`, replacing `<PROFILE>` with your old profile name.

Regardless of the above steps, you also need to follow these in order to successfully create your new profile:

1. Close the Editing Profile window.
2. On the drop-down menu, select the new profile you just created.
3. Restart `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Of course, the other simple approach is to tell all programs that your terminal does not have colour, by picking (or constructing) an appropriate terminal type.  I'm surprised that no-one has suggested it.

Comment: @JdeBP Ironically, contest is of good quality... this is my method, and it covers all programs. It does not show strange escape sequences or colors in parentheses or.... and, some programs do not have such an option.

Answer (score 0):

Setting terminal features (like colors) via the TERM variable works for me:

```
unset LS_COLORS
TERM=xterm-mono
export TERM
```

Comment: Never set TERM yourself