# How to change the background colour of directories in a mounted folder

Tags: colors

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox.

I have a mounted folder, and the directories in this folder have a background color of green as shown in the image.

[image: directory listing]

In my profile I have:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

How can I modify this so that the mounted directories have the default background color?

Comment: That's not related to the color *prompt*, it's related to the `dircolors` - and it's likely because the mounted drive is something like NTFS that is being mounted with execute permissions by default - see for example [dircolors/ls not being displayed correctly under NTFS drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208345/dircolors-ls-not-being-displayed-correctly-under-ntfs-drive)

Comment: If you're annoyed just delete the `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` line in your .bashrc. But I do not recommend that because it's telling you that NTFS is bad because it messes up execute permissions on everything it touches

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently disable color in default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818093/permanently-disable-color-in-default-terminal)

Comment: The suggestion from steeldriver was successful

Comment: This suggested link provided the solution: [dircolors-ls-not-being-displayed-correctly-under-ntfs-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208345/dircolors-ls-not-being-displayed-correctly-under-ntfs-drive)